# Querying in rails on attr_encrypted column

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, encryption, attr-encrypted

I have a ruby on rails app and I am using the `attr_encrypted` gem to encrypt some user info. It has a salt and IV so it is 2 way encrypted. The gem intercepts dynamic `find_by` to assist with querying, but that is not a sufficient query for my case as I care about the number of results.

Is there a way to query the table to return all results that match a given `secret`?

Here is the example. I have a `users` table and it has an encrypted `secret` attribute. The table thus has `encrypted_secret`, `encrypted_secret_iv`, and `encrypted_secret_salt`. If a user gave a secret of "abd123", how can I query the table to see how many others have also used "abc123" as their secret?

Answer (score 2):

You could also save an additional `secret_hash` of the unencrypted secret. If two records have the same `secret` then they will have the same `secret_hash` too.

Add something like the following to your model:

```
scope :by_secret, ->(secret) { 
  where(secret_hash: Digest::MD5.hexdigest(secret) 
}

before_save :generate_secret_hash

private 
def generate_secret_hash
  self.secret_hash = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(secret)
end
```

After that, you can query like this:

```
YourModel.by_secret('abd123').count
```

---

**Warning**

Storing MD5 hashes of passwords and other sensitive information is a security risk. Even if you cannot tell the plain text `secret` from a `secret_hash`, it allows you to tell when users share the same `secret`. Or - even worse - the MD5 hash might be available in an MD5-reverse-lookup-dictionary.

You must carefully trade off this security issue against the benefit of being able to query on that column.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if this is the only way to achieve querying on an encrypted column?

Comment: Since every column should have a different `salt` and `iv`, the only other way IMO would be to load all columns and check every decrypted secret against your search string.